# Intermittent extrememly long response times when downloading documents

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-vsphere, tomcat

I have a Java web application running om Tomcat 7 with an Apache httpd 2.2 fronting with mod_jk/AJP.

One part of the application is serving files (up to 4mb size). Now, normally this all runs very smooth with stable, low response-times. However, in rare instances (<0.1% of downloads), the downloadtime will go beyond 1 minute. After activating the ThreadStuckValve in Tomcat, I can see that the long responses seem to be stuck at

```
org.apache.tomcat.jni.Socket.sendbb(Native method)
```

i.e network I/O. At most, these long-running downloads take 5 minutes, which I strongly suspect is because of the default 300 second timout in Apache 2.2 (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html, "TimeOut directive").

To me, this looks like network problems. The Apache timeout (if that is what is kicking in at the 5 minute mark) indicates that ACK packets are not being transmitted correctly. My questions are what could be causing this? Closed browser at receiving end but socket not signaled as closed properly? Packet loss or some other network failure in transit? Where would I start troubleshooting this?

We're running Tomcat and Apache on Windows server 2008-R2 in a vmware virtualized server.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by running Wireshark and confirming your theory that the clients are misbehaving.  If that's the case, there's not a lot you can do to *prevent* that, but you can add intelligence to close these connections on your side more aggressively (both at Tomcat and Apache).

It's also worth noting that if this sort of misbehavior has significant impact on your application, you are susceptible to some simple DoS attack vectors ([Slowloris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowloris) comes to mind as one possibility, though something that makes it down to your application and disappears might be more effective).